# how to do clustering when the shape of data is (x,y,z)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

suppose i have 10 individual observations each of size (125,59). i want to group these 10 observations based on their 2d feature matrices ((125,59)).Is this possible without flattening every observation to 125*59 1D matrix ? I cant even implement PCA or LDA for feature extraction because the data is highly variant. Please note that i am trying to implement clustering through self organizing maps or neural networks. Deep learning and neural networks are completely related to the question asked.

Comment: Question is quite unclear, and has nothing to do with `neural-network` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.

Define an appropriate distance measure.

Then compute the 10x10 distance matrix, and run hierarchical clustering.

Comment: I can't. Defining an appropriate distance measure is your task - it's your data and problem, you have to know yourself what you want to be similar.